# Decode decrypt javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption

I am trying to decode this code i paste it here 
http://jsfiddle.net/U468Q/2/

bellow is just the part of it to show how it looks like

```
var _0xd1e4=["\x50\x2E\x31\x52\x3D\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x36\x2E\x31\x4D\x28\x7B\x31\x78\x3A\x27\x42\x27\x2C\
```

anyone can help or guide me in the right direction!

Comment: It attempts to eval syntactically invalid code

Comment: it's mostly just dean edward's packer with long single-char names. instead of (p,a,c,k,e,r), we see (_0x538fx1, _0x538fx2, _0x538fx3, _0x538fx4, _0x538fx5, _0x538fx6) ...

Answer (score 2):

## [JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) does deobfuscating.

Comment: I beautified the code and updated the jsfiddle but can't understand much!

Comment: I can't help you any further.